# Is there a resnet implementation using mxnet gluon api?

Tags: mxnet, resnet

I am looking for the model file definition for a resnet implementation using the mxnet gluon api. The model zoo only provides pre-trained models:
https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/api/python/gluon/model_zoo.html

I am looking for the code implementing the resent model.

Comment: Does this help: https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/blob/master/python/mxnet/gluon/model_zoo/vision/resnet.py ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the example from mxnet github repo:

https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/blob/master/python/mxnet/gluon/model_zoo/vision/resnet.py